# $x=\left (1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\ln(2)},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\ln(3)},\dots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)},\dots\right)\in l_p$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Show that:
> $$x=\left(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\ln(2)},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\ln(3)},\dots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)},\dots\right)\in c_0$$
>
> belongs to the space $l_p$ for $p\geqslant 2 $

I tried to write down the sum like this $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}$, the problem is that when $n=1$, the series diverges to infinity. I have no clue how to write these series so that it does not diverge. Even if I used $l_2$ norm it would still diverge at $1$.

**Question**:

How should I solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Treat $n=1$ separately. Your sum and the element don't match so of course you might get gibberish.

Comment: After you fix that, you can solve this with the integral test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $p\geq 2$
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p/2}\ln^p(n)}\leq \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\leq \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \int_{x=n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}\,dx = \int_{x=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}\,dx.$$

Comment: You are excluding the $n=2$ once $\ln(2)<1$. Is it viable?

Comment: It suffices to show the convergence of  $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p/2}\ln^p(n)}$ for any $n_0\geq 2$. Note that $\|x\|_p^p=1+\frac{1}{2^{p/2}\ln^p(2)}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p/2}\ln^p(n)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I am having problems with the series $\sum_\limits{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}$. I am trying the comparison test to find a smaller divergent sum, but I have no idea how can I decrease the sum even further. I am doing it for $l_1$.

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}\geq \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I do not how to explain it.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}\geqslant \frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$, but I do not how should I remove the $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Where does the exponent $\sqrt{n}$ come from??

Comment: $\ln(x)\leqslant x$, so $\ln(n^{\sqrt{n}})\leqslant n^{\sqrt{n}})$

Comment: @PedroGomes I don't understand.What are you trying to show?

Comment: Since $\ln(n^{\sqrt{n}})\leqslant n^{\sqrt{n}}$ then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}\geqslant \frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$

Comment: Why don't you use the simpler inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}\geq \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Because I do not know how I go from left expression to the right

Comment: It is equivalent to $\sqrt{n}\geq \ln(n)$ which holds for all $n\geq 1$. It suffices to show it for $n\geq 4$ where $n\to \sqrt{n}-\ln(n)$ is increasing (take the derivative).

Answer (score 1):

There exists $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\geq k\;(\;0<\sqrt n\;\log n <\sqrt {n+1}\;\log (n+1)\;)$ so apply the Cauchy Condensation Test . This test also shows that $x\not \in l_p$ for $1\leq p<2.$